# JSON deserialize in vb.net code behind

Tags: json

I am a java developer and I am working on .net first time. I have used JSON with YUI, but this is first time I am using JQUERY. I have converted Java script object to JSON string using `JSON.stringify()` and I am getting the same JSON string in code behind, but when I tried to deserialize to the .net object, I am getting the value for property which is Integer, but I not getting the value for String object.

// Client Side

```
$("#ButtonSave").click(function () {

    //convert gridview to JSON
    var jsonData = new Array();
    $.map($("table[id*=Gridview1] tr"), function (item, index) {
        if ($(item).find("input[type=text]").length > 0) {
            jsonData[index] = new Object();
            jsonData[index].charge = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtCharge]").val();
            jsonData[index].produce = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtProduce]").val();         
            jsonData[index].weight = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtWeight]").val();
            jsonData[index].feet = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtFeet]").val();
            jsonData[index].orderNumber = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtOrderNumber]").val(); 
            jsonData[index].comments = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtComments]").val();
        }
    });

    var jsonStringData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: "Correction.aspx",
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 10000,
        data: "jsonData=" + jsonStringData
    })
    .error(function () {
        alert('Error');
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        alert('Success');
    });
});
```

//Code Behind

```
 If Request.Form("jsonData") IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim cita As New TurnDetailVO
        Dim ser As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim items As List(Of TurnDetailVO) = ser.Deserialize(Of List(Of TurnDetailVO))(Request.Form("jsonData"))

        items.RemoveAt(0)

        For Each cita In items
            Console.WriteLine(cita.CHARGE_ID, cita.PROD_ID)
        Next

 End If
```

// Value Object

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

Public Class TurnDetailVO

Private _CHARGE As String
Private _PROD As String
Private _WEIGHT As Integer
Private _FEET As Integer
Private _ORDER_NUMBER As String    
Private _COMMENTS As String


Public Sub New()

    _CHARGE = " "
    _PROD = " "
    _WEIGHT = 0 
    _FEET = 0
    _ORDER_NUMBER = " "
    _COMMENTS = " "

End Sub



Public Property CHARGE() As String
    Get
        Return _CHARGE
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _CHARGE = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PROD() As String
    Get
        Return _PROD
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _PROD = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property WEIGHT() As Integer
    Get
        Return _WEIGHT
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _WEIGHT = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property FEET() As Integer
    Get
        Return _FEET
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _FEET = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ORDER_NUMBER() As String
    Get
        Return _ORDER_NUMBER
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _ORDER_NUMBER = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property COMMENTS() As String
    Get
        Return _COMMENTS
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _COMMENTS = value
    End Set
End Property



Public Function Clone() As TurnDetailVO
    Return DirectCast(Me.MemberwiseClone(), TurnDetailVO)
End Function

End Class
```

// JSON String

```
"[null,
{"charge":"T860243","produce":"S877020","weight":"13188","feet":"2898","orderNumber":"AN46270","comments":""},
{"charge":"T860243","produce":"S877021","weight":"13538","feet":"2978","orderNumber":"AN46270","comments":""},
{"charge":"T860243","produce":"S877022","weight":"30118","feet":"6618","orderNumber":"AN46270","comments":""},
{"charge":"T860243","produce":"S877023","weight":"23455","feet":"3345","orderNumber":"AN46270","comments":""}]"
```

Comment: It would help to have the JSON prior to deserialization. Could you edit your question with the content of `Request.Form("jsonData")`?

Comment: This is the json string I am getting in Request object in code behind.                                      Request.Form("jsonData") = 
"[null,
{"charge":"T860243","produce":"S877020","weight":"13188","feet":"2898","orderNumber":"AN46270","comments":""},
{"charge":"T860243","produce":"S877021","weight":"13538","feet":"2978","orderNumber":"AN46270","comments":""},
{"charge":"T860243","produce":"S877022","weight":"30118","feet":"6618","orderNumber":"AN46270","comments":""},
{"charge":"T860243","produce":"S877023","weight":"23455","feet":"3345","orderNumber":"AN46270","comments":""}]"

Comment: This are the values I am getting after the deserialization.     _CHARGE = " ", _PROD = " ", _WEIGHT = 13188,  _FEET = 2898,  _ORDER_NUMBER = " ", _COMMENTS = "" I am expecting some values in _CHARGE , _PROD,  _ORDER_NUMBER  , _COMMENTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the deserializtion isn't behaving as expected due to two of your field names being different.

If I changed the property names `PROD` to `PRODUCE` and `ORDER_NUMBER` to `ORDERNUMBER` I could get it working. Note that you can leave the private field names as they are, it is just the property names that need to change.